# How to pass in a @IntDef annotation type as function parameter

Tags: java, android, annotations

I have a annotation type defined as

```
@IntDef({
  MOOD.HAPPY,
  MOOD.SAD,
})
public @interface MOOD {
  int HAPPY = 0,
  int SAD = 1,
}
```

Now I have a function defined as

```
SomeFunctionName(MOOD mood) {
  doingSomething...
}
```

I don't know how can I pass a MOOD value to this function. Compiler always complains type couldn't convert
For example, I tried

```
SomeFunctionName(MOOD.HAPPY)
SomeFunctionName(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `SomeFunctionName` is declared to take a MOOD, but you are trying to pass an integer.

This compiles fine:

```java
@interface MOOD1 {
  int HAPPY = 0;
  int SAD = 1;
}

interface MOOD2 {
  int HAPPY = 0;
  int SAD = 1;
}

public class SO67518698 {
  void m1(MOOD1 mood) {}
  void m2(MOOD2 mood) {}
  void m3(int x) {}

  void client() {
    m3(MOOD1.HAPPY);
    m3(0);
}
```

You should also think about whether you are trying to define an interface (use `interface`) or an annotation (use `@interface`).

Comment: Exactly, my question here is about how to construct a MOOD1 value so I can pass it to the `SomeFunctionName`. In you example, How to use m1 function

Comment: `HAPPY`, `SAD`, and `0` are `int` values.  They are not MOOD values.  You would first need to created a MOOD value, for instance by defining a MOOD enum, or by defining a subclass of MOOD2.